# Trigonometric Identities Like $A \sin(x) + B \cos(y) = \cdots$

Tags: trigonometry

Are there any identities for trigonometric equations of the form:

$$A\sin(x) + B\sin(y) = \cdots$$
$$A\sin(x) + B\cos(y) = \cdots$$
$$A\cos(x) + B\cos(y) = \cdots$$

I can't find any mention of them anywhere, maybe there is a good reason why there aren't identities for these? Thanks!

Comment: I have heard of asin(x) + bcos(x) = Acos(x+alpha) where A is in terms of a and b .Without a relation between x and y we cannot combine because of the different coefficients a and b . had they been 1 it is possible

Comment: Perhaps you could be a little bit more specific in what kind of identity you are expecting. Personally I find your initial form simple enough but perhaps you are bothered by the $+$ which makes you unable to do a certain type of calculation?

Comment: One simple special case is the identities saying $\sin x+\sin y$ $=\text{a single term, which is a product of half-angle functions}$, and similarly for $\cos x+\cos y$ and $\sin x+\cos y$.

Comment: This seems related: [Identity for a weighted sum of sines / sines with different amplitudes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397984#398977)

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664525/prove-2d-rotation-by-theta-is-a-linear-transformation-using-trig-identities-f

Answer (score 5):

Since

$$
A \cos(a+b) = A \cos(a) \cos(b) - A \sin(a) \sin(b) \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) \\
B \cos(a-b) = B \cos(a) \cos(b) + B \sin(a) \sin(b) \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
$$

(1) + (2) gives

$$
A \cos(x) + B \cos(y) = (A+B) \cos(\frac{x+y}{2}) \cos(\frac{x-y}{2}) + (B-A) \sin(\frac{x+y}{2}) \sin(\frac{x-y}{2})
$$

where

$$
x = a + b \\ y = a - b
$$

substitute

$$
Q = (A+B) \cos(\frac{x-y}{2}) \\
R = (B-A) \sin(\frac{x-y}{2}) \\
P = \frac{x+y}{2}
$$

then

$$
A \cos(x) + B \cos(y) = Q \cos P + R \sin P = \sqrt{Q^2+R^2} \cos(P-\phi)
$$

where

$$
\sin \phi = \frac{R}{\sqrt{Q^2+R^2}} \\
\cos \phi = \frac{Q}{\sqrt{Q^2+R^2}}
$$

Comment: Thanks for providing a formula for $A \cos (x) + B \cos (y)$. Can you also share a formula for $A \sin (x) + B \sin (y)$?

Answer (score 1):

there are no general formula for these expressions.but may  exist when  $A$ and $B$ are interrelated .

For example consider triangle  $ABC$ where $a,b,\text{ and }c $ are the sides of the triangle and $A,B,\text{ and }C$ are the respective angles opposite to  $a,b,\text{ and }c $ then
$$c = a\cos B + b\cos A $$
here this is because $a,b ,A\text{ and }B$ are interrelated by laws of triangle.

therefore random values of the angles and the coefficients will not satisfy to form general formula.

Answer (score 0):

Since the proof was asked for A*sin(x)+B*sin(y), based on the prior answer, I expand this time with a Python example for some verification:

$$
A \sin(a+b) = A \sin(a) \cos(b) + A \cos(a) \sin(b) \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) \\
B \sin(a-b) = B \sin(a) \cos(b) - B \cos(a) \sin(b) \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
$$

(1) + (2) gives

$$
A \sin(x) + B \sin(y) = (A+B) \sin(\frac{x+y}{2}) \cos(\frac{x-y}{2}) + (A-B) \cos(\frac{x+y}{2}) \sin(\frac{x-y}{2})
$$

where

$$
x = a + b \\ y = a - b
$$

substitute

$$
Q = (A+B) \sin(\frac{x+y}{2}) \\
R = (A-B) \cos(\frac{x+y}{2}) \\
P = \frac{x-y}{2}
$$

then

$$
A \sin(x) + B \sin(y) = Q \cos P + R \sin P = \sqrt{Q^2+R^2} \sin(P+\phi)
$$

where

$$
\tan \phi = \frac{Q}{R} \\
$$

Proof in Python:

```
import numpy as np
A, B, x, y = 3, 4, 5, 6
Q, R, P = (A+B)*np.sin((x+y)/2), (A-B)*np.cos((x+y)/2), (x-y)/2
print(A*np.sin(x)+B*np.sin(y), np.sqrt(Q*Q+R*R)*np.sin(P+np.arctan2(Q, R)))
```

Result:

```
-3.9944348167851187 -3.9944348167851187
```

Answer (score -1):

$A \, \cos(x) + B \, \cos(y)= C \, \cos(z)$, where,
$$ C = \sqrt{(A \, \cos(x) + B \, \cos(y))^2 + (A \, \sin(x) + B \, \sin(y))^2}, $$
and
$$ z = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{A \, \sin(x) + B \, \sin(y)}{A \, \cos(x) + B \, \cos(y)}\right). $$

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Was this answer downvoted because it is incorrect, or because it was poorly formatted? Sources (or proofs) would be nice. 

I stumbled across this question and am also looking for formulas for $A \cos (x) + B \cos (y)$ and $A \sin (x) + B \sin (y)$.