# Prove 2D rotation by $\theta$ is a linear transformation using trig identities for $r\cos(\alpha) + s\cos(\beta)$ and $r\sin(\alpha) + s\sin(\beta)$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, proof-writing, linear-transformations, signal-processing

**Theorem**

The rotation by $\theta$ function $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined for $\vec{x}%=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}
    =\begin{bmatrix}r\cos(\alpha) \\ r\sin(\alpha)\end{bmatrix}$ by
\begin{align*}
    T(\vec{x})
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        r\cos(\alpha+\theta) \\
        r\sin(\alpha+\theta)
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
is a linear function.

**Proof**

1. First we show $T(c\vec{a}) = cT(\vec{a})$:

   \begin{align*}
           T(c \vec{a})
           &=T\left(c \begin{bmatrix} r \cos(\alpha) \\ r \sin(\alpha) \end{bmatrix}\right) \\
           &=T(\begin{bmatrix} cr \cos(\alpha) \\ cr \sin(\alpha) \end{bmatrix}) \\
           &=\begin{bmatrix} cr \cos(\alpha+\theta) \\ cr \sin(\alpha+\theta) \end{bmatrix} \\
           &=c\begin{bmatrix} r \cos(\alpha+\theta) \\ r \sin(\alpha+\theta) \end{bmatrix} \\
           &=c T\left(\begin{bmatrix} r \cos (\alpha) \\ r \sin (\alpha) \end{bmatrix}\right) \\
           &=c T(\vec{a})
       \end{align*}
2. Next, we show $T(\vec{a}+\vec{b}) = T(\vec{a})+T(\vec{b})$:

   \begin{align}
          T \left(\vec{a}+\vec{b}\right)
          &= T\left(\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix}\right)\\
          &= T\left(\begin{bmatrix} r \cos(\alpha) \\ r \sin(\alpha) \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix} s \cos(\beta) \\ s \sin (\beta) \end{bmatrix}\right)\\
          &=T\left(\begin{bmatrix} r \cos(\alpha) + s \cos(\beta) \\ r \sin(\alpha) + s \sin (\beta) \end{bmatrix}\right)\\
          & \ \ \vdots \\
   & \ \ \vdots \\
          &=\begin{bmatrix} r \cos(\alpha + \theta) \\ r \sin (\alpha + \theta) \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} s \cos (\beta + \theta) \\ s \sin (\beta + \theta) \end{bmatrix}\\
          &=T\left(\begin{bmatrix} r \cos(\alpha) \\ r \sin (\alpha) \end{bmatrix}\right) + T\left(\begin{bmatrix} s \cos (\beta) \\ s \sin (\beta) \end{bmatrix}\right)\\
          &=T(\vec{a})+T(\vec{b})
       \end{align}

---

I was able to successfully prove part (1), but am having trouble with part (2). I have checked some resources, including

- ["Linear combinations" section of Wikipedia's List of Trig Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations)
- ["Addition" section of Wikipedia's article on Phasors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#Addition),
- [Trigonometric Identities Like $A \sin(x) + B \cos(y) = \cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468475/trigonometric-identities-like-a-sinx-b-cosy-cdots)
- [Identity for a weighted sum of sines / sines with different amplitudes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397984/identity-for-a-weighted-sum-of-sines-sines-with-different-amplitudes)

in order to combine

\begin{align*}
&r \cos(\alpha) + s \cos(\beta), \\
&r \sin(\alpha) + s \sin(\beta)
\end{align*}

Could anyone help flesh out the missing steps of this proof?

**Note** I know this transformation can be expressed as multiplication by the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$, and all matrix multiplications are linear, but I would like to avoid this approach and show the missing steps directly using trig identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find $t$ and $\gamma$ such that
$$
r\cos\alpha + s\cos\beta=t\cos\gamma\tag1
$$
and
$$
r\sin\alpha + s\sin\beta = t\sin\gamma.\tag2
$$
(Why is this possible? Divide equation (2) by (1) to get a formula for $\tan \gamma$, then deduce $t$ using either equation. This requires us to exclude edge cases that cause division by zero.)

Then
$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix} r \cos(\alpha) + s \cos(\beta) \\ r \sin(\alpha) + s \sin (\beta) \end{bmatrix}\right)=T\left(\begin{bmatrix}t\cos\gamma\\t\sin\gamma\end{bmatrix}\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}t\cos(\gamma+\theta)\\t\sin(\gamma+\theta)\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now expand out $t\cos(\gamma+\theta)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
t\cos(\gamma+\theta)&=
t\cos\gamma\cos\theta-t\sin\gamma\sin\theta\\
&=(r\cos\alpha+s\cos\beta)\cos\theta - (r\sin\alpha+s\sin\beta)\sin\theta\\
&=r(\cos\alpha\cos\theta-\sin\alpha\sin\theta) +s(\cos\beta\cos\theta - \sin\beta\sin\theta)\\
&=r\cos(\alpha+\theta) + s\cos(\beta+\theta)
\end{aligned}
$$
The calculation for $t\sin(\gamma+\theta)$ is similar.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! But how would one compute $t$ and $\gamma$? Is there a formula for these constants in terms of $r$, $s$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$? Thanks again.

Comment: The ratio of (2) to (1) gives $\tan \gamma = \frac{r\sin\alpha + s\sin\beta}{r\cos\alpha + s\cos\beta}$ so $\gamma=\arctan\left(\frac{r\sin\alpha + s\sin\beta}{r\cos\alpha + s\cos\beta}\right)$. Plug $\gamma$ into (1) to obtain $t$. In order for the proof to proceed, it is sufficient to show that $\gamma$ and $t$ exist.

Comment: Sorry for still not seeing it, but why is it the case that equations (1) and (2) are true? Is this a trig identity? How would one go about calculating $t$ and $\gamma$ - what's the formula for these constants?

Comment: Equations (1) and (2) are equations that $t$ and $\gamma$ must satisfy. They are essentially *defining* $t$ and $\gamma$. For any given $r, s, \alpha, \beta$ it is possible to find $t$ and $\gamma$ that satisfy these conditions, by following the recipe in my first comment

Comment: I am trying to be convinced that the linear combination of cosines is another cosine, and that the linear combination of sines is another sine. So far I am not seeing any proof of that.

Comment: The assertion is *not* that the linear combination of cosines is another cosine--there is a factor of $t$ as well. If you have calculated $t$ and $\gamma$ according to the above recipe, you can confirm that equations (1) and (2) are now true.

Comment: I think I understand. We are not claiming a linear combination of cosine waves is a scaled up cosine wave using a Fourier Series argument or something like that, right? We're just saying given fixed angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we can find another angle $\gamma$ (and an appropriate scalar $t$) to make equation (1) true.

Comment: We would have to choose $\gamma=\arctan\left(\frac{r \sin \alpha + s \sin \beta}{r \cos \alpha + s \cos \beta}\right)$ and $t=\frac{r \cos \alpha + s \cos \beta}{\cos \gamma} = \frac{r \cos \alpha + s \cos \beta}{\cos \left(\arctan\left(\frac{r \sin \alpha + s \sin \beta}{r \cos \alpha + s \cos \beta}\right)\right)}$. Therefore $\gamma$ and $t$ are uniquely defined in terms of the constants $\alpha$, $\beta$, $r$, and $s$, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, the values $t$ and $\gamma$ depend on the current values for $r,s,\alpha,\beta$; equations (1) and (2) are not identities in the sense that $\sin 2\theta = 2 \sin\theta\cos\theta$ is an identity.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that you've mentioned that you prefer to avoid using the matrix form of the rotation. Still, I wanted at least to point out that the matrix form can be derived using trigonometric identities for sum of angles (since you seem to prefer trigonometry).

If the vector $\vec x$ is given by
\begin{align*}
x_1&=r\cos\alpha\\
x_2&=r\sin\alpha
\end{align*}
then you have
\begin{align*}
y_1&=r\cos(\alpha+\theta)=r(\cos\alpha\cos\theta-\sin\alpha\sin\theta)=x_1\cos\theta-x_2\sin\theta\\
y_2&=r\sin(\alpha+\theta)=r(\cos\alpha\sin\theta+\sin\alpha\cos\theta)=x_1\sin\theta+x_2\cos\theta
\end{align*}
which gives you the expression in the matrix form. (And in this form, it is easy to verify linearity.)