# Addition of Two Cosine Functions Into a Single Cosine Function

Tags: trigonometry, harmonic-analysis

Recently I was looking at modelling tides with the form of $a*\cos(bx)+c*\cos(dx)$. Can I combine these two terms into a single function? I realise that $\cos(bx)+\cos(dx)$ becomes $2\cos\bigl(\frac{(b+d)}{2}\bigr)*\cos\bigl(\frac{(b-d)}{2}\bigr)$, and that I can take $a$ out as a common factor; how do I combine $a*\cos(bx)+c*\cos(dx)$ into one cosine function?

Comment: If $b,d$ are rationally independent your function is not periodic so can't be written as a single cosine.

Comment: You have varied both frequency and amplitude, which complicates things. Is there any possibility you can fix one of them?

Comment: Currently I have $b$ and $d$ as rationally dependant values (I think) - the function is periodic @coffeemath.

Comment: Because I'm only modelling tides I can make all the variables constant for a specific situation @Soham. I was just interested to know if there was a process to combine the functions.

Comment: @AngusRogers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397984/identity-for-a-weighted-sum-of-sines-sines-with-different-amplitudes