# Critical point of $F(x) = \int_0^{\pi x} \frac{d \theta}{ a \cos \theta - b \sin \theta}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $a,b \in R$ such that $a>2b>0$ and let $F:[0, \frac{\pi}{3}] \rightarrow R$ be defined by

$$F(x) = \int_0^{\pi x} \frac{d \theta}{ a \cos \theta - b \sin \theta}$$

How can one find a critical point of the function $F(x) - \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{a-b}x$ on the interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{3} )$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**.  Differentiating, you need
$$\frac{\pi}{a\cos(\pi x)-b\sin(\pi x)}-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{a-b}=0\ .$$
You can solve this by converting the first denominator into the form $\cos(\pi x+\alpha)$.

Comment: i tried  use you hint but i can't find the derivative of $F(x)$, for this i tried use the FTC but i stuck

Comment: You will need to use FTC and also the chain rule.  It might help if you start by substituting $u=\pi x$, then use $dF/dx=(dF/du)(du/dx)$.

Comment: excuse me but $ cos( \pi x + \alpha) = cos( \pi x) cos( \alpha) - sen( \pi x) sin(  \alpha)$ how can this equal to  $ a cos( \pi x ) - b sin( \pi x) $ ?

Comment: [See if this helps](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213545/solving-a-trignometric-equation-of-form-a-sin-x-b-cos-x-c).