# Solving $a\sin x + b\cos x = c $

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose $a\sin x + b\cos x = c $ .
My teacher told me that with changing variable we can solve it by this : $(c + b) t^2 - 2at + (c-b) = 0$ where $t = \tan \frac{x}{2}$ . I thought it is true always but today found a problem . When we define $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ with $\tan \frac{x}{2}$ , we should consider $\cos \frac{x}{2} \not = 0$ and $x \not = 2k\pi + \pi$  but it can be the answer of the main equation (i.e. $a\sin x + b\cos x = c $ ) ! So , that formula is incomplete ?

Comment: You can either check for those few points or allow $t=\pm\infty$. No big deal.

Comment: If you find something ambiguous in your teacher's saying, then you can use different substitutions , as $$sin(x)=t , cos(x)=\sqrt{1-t^2}$$ which will lead you to a quadratic equation which is easier to solve

Comment: observe that $$\cos(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-t^2}$$

Comment: ...and in particular, you have to make BOTH substitutions for $\cos x$ to get all solutions.

Comment: @AtulMishra yes I agree with your teacher and my below solution is completely same to what your teacher indicates you to do. But fair enough I have elaborated it by speaking the steps I followed in that method of solving.

Comment: Oops, this is a duplicate : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213545/solving-trigonometric-equations-of-the-form-a-sin-x-b-cos-x-c?rq=1

Comment: For reference, the approach your teacher suggests is discussed on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution.

Comment: @Semiclassical wow it has a name. Good to know !!

Comment: Can't we also use http://www.mash.dept.shef.ac.uk/Resources/web-rcostheta-alphaetc.pdf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(x)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(x)\right)=c$$
and $$\cos(\phi)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
$$\sin(\phi)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
therefore we get
$$\sin(x+\phi)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
or you write
$$2\,{\frac {a\tan \left( x/2 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {b \left( 1- \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right) 
 \right) ^{2}}}=c
$$ with $$\tan(x/2)=t$$ as your teacher said

Comment: Okay but I'm talking about losing some answers with that formula .

Comment: why should you lose answers? i have never squared the given equation

Comment: You lose answers because $\tan(x/2)$ could be "infinite", i.e., because $x/2$ might not be in the domain of $\tan$, and yet $x$ might still be a solution. Squaring is not the only way to reduce a domain; the problem arises in the same way that a negative number might not be the square of anything, but still could be a solution to some equation.

Comment: ok in this case you can take the other way

Comment: @JohnHughes So if I check $x = 2k\pi + \pi $ , then I can use that formula ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How we can define $\cos(\phi)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ ?

Comment: yes you can use this formula, but you must check that case, at the end or in the beginning

Comment: this angle $\phi$ exists in every case except $$a=b=0$$

Comment: How we can prove $-1\le\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\le 1$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W If $ a \ne 0 $ or $ b \ne 0 $,  we have $  \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \ge \lvert {a} \rvert \implies \lvert {{a} \over {\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}}\rvert \le 1 \implies  1 \ge {{a} \over {\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}} \ge -1 $

Answer (score 0):

NOte that:$${\color{Red}{a \sin x+ b \cos x=c \\ \frac{|a|}{a} \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin (x+\alpha)=c\\ \tan \alpha=\frac{b}{a}}  }\\\sin (x+\alpha)=\frac{|a|}{a}.\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ This is general form

Comment: Why you are using $\frac{|a|}{a}$ ? I think the above answer is the same .