# Trigonometric equations.

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

$\sin x + \cos x = \min\{1, k^2-4k+6, k \in \mathbb{R}\}$

I assume that the question looks for the minimum of the two.

Thus,  $\sin x + \cos x = \min(1,2)= 1$

$\implies \sin\Big(\dfrac x 2 \Big)\cos\Big(\dfrac x 2\Big)= \sin^2 \Big(\dfrac x2\Big) $.  On solving we get, $x = 2n\pi$ or $x= 2n\pi + \dfrac\pi2$ , $n \in \mathbb{I}$.

However, answer given is $x = n\pi + (-1)^n\dfrac \pi 4 - \dfrac \pi 4$.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method**$\#1:$,

For $x = n\pi + (-1)^n\dfrac \pi 4 - \dfrac \pi 4$

if $n$ is even, $=2m$(say) where $m$ is any integer   $$x=2m\pi$$

What if $n$ is odd, $=2m+1$(say) where $m$ is any integer ?

So, the answer is a compact form of what you have reached at.

**Method**$\#2:$,

$$\sin x+\cos x=1\iff\sin\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)=\sin\dfrac\pi4$$

See general solution [here](http://www.kshitij-iitjee.com/Maths/Trigonometric-Functions/trigonometric-equations.aspx).

**Method**$\#3:$,

$$\sin x+\cos x=1\iff\cos\left(x-\dfrac\pi4\right)=\cos\dfrac\pi4$$

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here!

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, clearly answers the question.

Comment: @Abcd, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213545/solving-trigonometric-equations-of-the-form-a-sin-x-b-cos-x-c

Answer (score 1):

Since $ k^2-4k+6 =(k-2)^2+2$, then 
$\min\{1, k^2-4k+6, k \in \mathbb{R}\} = \min\{1,2\} = 1$.

So you have to solve $\sin x + \cos x = 1$

Since $\sin \frac{\pi}{4} = \cos \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, then

\begin{align}
   \sin x \sin \frac{\pi}{4} + \cos x \cos \frac{\pi}{4} 
   &= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \\
   \cos \left(x - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)&= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \\
   x - \frac{\pi}{4} &= 2\pi k\pm \frac{\pi}{4} \\
   x &\in \{2\pi k : k \in \mathbb Z\} \cup 
          \{2\pi k + \frac{\pi}{2} : k \in \mathbb Z\}
\end{align}