# Solving trigonometric equations of the form $a \tan x + b \sin x = c$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the general solution of the trigonometric equation: $a \tan x + b \sin x = c$, where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ are any real numbers.

---

I've tried to use the identity $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and then multiplying the original equation by $\cos x$ in order to get the following form of the equation: $a\sin x + b\sin x\cos x = c \cos x$, Also I've tried to divide the original equation by $\sin x$ (supposing that $\sin x \neq 0$) in order to get the following form of the equation: $\frac{a}{\cos x} + b = \frac{c}{\sin x}$, or put in another form: $\frac{c}{\sin x}-\frac{a}{\cos x} = b$, and then I've tried to use a method similar to the method used in the answers given to this question asked here ” [Solving trigonometric equations of the form $a\sin x + b\cos x = c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213545/solving-trigonometric-equations-of-the-form-a-sin-x-b-cos-x-c) ” but wasn't able to progress anywhere to something that gives me the general solution.

Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: Using also $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$ for every real $x$ should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same strategy as given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1327254/99220) in the thread you linked

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$, then $a\tan(\theta) + b\sin(\theta) = c$ is equivalent to

$$ -ia\frac{z -\tfrac 1z}{z + \tfrac 1z}-\tfrac 12 ib(z-\tfrac 1z) = c $$

Hence

$$ a(z-\tfrac 1z) + \tfrac 12b(z^2-\tfrac{1}{z^2}) = ic(z+\tfrac 1z)$$

Which, after multiplying by $z^2$, is a polynomial equation of degree $4$, so in principle algebraically solveable. It won't be pretty but if you really want an algebraic solution you will be able to get it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Small thought, not a solution:

When you get to 
$$
\frac{c}{\sin x}-\frac{a}{\cos x} = b
$$
you can put things over a common denominator:
$$
\frac{c\cos x}{\sin x \cos x}-\frac{a \sin x }{\sin x \cos x} = b
$$
and multiply through to get
$$
c\cos x-a \sin x = b\sin x \cos x = \frac{b}{2} \sin(2x)
$$
where the left-hand side can be simplified (using an arctangent of $c/a$ or $a/c$ -- I can never remember which) to the form
$$
\pm A \sin (x + d)
$$
This now gets you an offset sine equal to a double-frequency sine...which really doesn't seem a lot easier to me, but might conceivably be of some use to you.

===========

Another alternative is to say $u = \sin x, v = \cos x$, and let $w$ be a third variable. Then your problem has the form
$$
a \frac{u}{v} + bu = c
$$
which can be shuffled into 
$$
au + buv = cv
$$
We "homogenize" this by throwing in factors of $w$ to get
$$
auw + buv - cvw = 0
$$
and this defines a homogenous polynomial in three unknowns, i.e., it defines a curve on $\Bbb RP^2$. If you can find a point $(u, v, w)$ on this curve, then $(u', v', 1) = (u/w, v/w, 1)$ is a point satisfying the $uv$ form of your equation, but is only of interest to you if $u'^2 + v'^2 = 1$.

Even so, if there happened to be a nice way to parameterize the solution to that homogeneous equation on $\Bbb RP^2$, this might lead to something useful.

Comment: Yes, indeed, by setting $A=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}$ and $B=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ we get that $-1 \leq A,B \leq 1$ and that $A^2+B^2=1$ and thus there exist $ \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\cos \beta = A$ and $\sin \beta = B$ and we can write the equation in the form $\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\cos(x+\beta)=\sqrt{a^2+c^2}(\cos\beta \cos x - \sin\beta \sin x)=\sqrt{a^2+c^2}(A\cos x - B\sin x)= c\cos x- a\sin x = \frac{b}{2}\sin (2x)$   and the equation stays difficult to solve.