# Why use the Weierstrass Substitution to solve $a = -x \sin\gamma + z \cos\gamma$ for $\gamma$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I've come across a deceptively simple algebraic equation involving trig functions.

> Solve the following for $\gamma$:
>   $$a = -x \sin(\gamma) + z \cos(\gamma)$$
>   where $a$, $x$, $z$ are constants.

After realizing that I didn't know how to solve it, I plugged it into Wolfram Alpha. The step-by-step solutions mention something called [Weierstrass ("tangent half-angle") Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution). After researching this method, I've learned that most examples are methods for solving integrals.

> My question is: Why does the Weierstrass Substitution work for the above equation?

Comment: "Why does it work?" It works *because it works*. "Why use it?" It can be a hassle to invoke a host of identities to manipulate a trig eqn into a solvable form. The Weierstrass Substitution cuts through the clutter to provide a purely-mechanical way of writing trig functions in terms of a common quantity, with an added benefit of converting what could be a convoluted trig eqn into a straightforward polynomial one. Polynomials are "easy" to solve, after all. The trade-off is that you might miss an insightful trig-specific approach; see, eg, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/213545/409).

Answer (score 0):

$$ a = -x \sin \gamma + z \cos \gamma  $$
$$ \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}} = \sin \gamma \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}} + \cos \gamma  \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}  $$
so take $\delta$ with $\tan \delta = \frac{-z}{x},$  $\cos \delta = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}$ and $\sin \delta = \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}.$
Now $\delta$ is solvable and
$$ \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}} = \sin (\gamma + \delta) $$