# Trigonometric Identity for tidyup of an exam question

Tags: trigonometry

I need to show that $\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}=\tan\left({\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)$ using the A-level MF26 identities.

I have looked at converting $1+\cos\theta$ to $2\cos^2\left({\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)$ but am still a bit stuck.  Would welcome any suggestions.

Comment: I don't know MF26, but [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3595919/elementary-proof-of-tangent-half-angle-formula?noredirect=1&lq=1) is an elementary proof. In the duplicate below, also $\tan \left ( \frac{\alpha}{2} \right ) = \frac{\sin \alpha}{1 + \cos \alpha}$ is shown with the duplication formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the double-angle identities
\begin{align*}
\sin(2x) & = 2\sin x\cos x\\
\cos(2x) & = 2\cos^2x - 1
\end{align*}
with $x = \frac{\theta}{2}$ yields
$$\frac{\sin\theta}{1 + \cos\theta} = \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{1 + 2\cos^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) - 1} = \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{2\cos^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)} = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)} = \tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
provided that $\theta \neq (2k + 1)\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.