# What topic does this equation $ 3\sin x -4\cos x = a$ belong to?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

Question : Find the values of the parameter *a* for which the equation   $ 3\sin x -4\cos x = a$  has a solution.

Not looking for the answer here but can somebody please recommend me a book or a website to get sufficient knowledge on this topic so that I'm able to answer this question? (I'm familiar with parametric equations involving only unknowns, but this is my first time seeing trigonometric functions in one)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-value-of-y-Asinx+Bcosx-where-and-b-are-positive-constants-A-B,does this help?

Comment: It is trigonometric equation. [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/213545/782505).

Comment: @Quantum it shows here "error 404"

Comment: @SarGe : Correct me if I'm wrong but after some calculation, I got $ 5sin(x+b)=a$. So because both $sinx$ and $cosx$ has to be between -1 and 1, 5 is multiplied with both of these numbers to get all values of the parameter a. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Use the derivative of $f(x)=3\sin x -4\cos x -a$ to find the minimum and maximum values of $f(x)$

Comment: The expression $3\sin x - 4\cos x$ is a [linear combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations) of sines and cosines.

Answer (score 0):

$$3 \sin x-4 \cos x=a \implies (3/5) \sin x-(4/5) \cos x=a/5\implies \sin (x-t)=a/5, \tan t=4/3~~~~(1)$$
This equation will be valid if $-5 \le a\le 5.$ Solutions of (1) are given by
$$x= n\pi+(-1)^n \sin^{-1}(a/5)+t, n \in I$$

Comment: Can explain how you get  $-5 \le a\le 5$ ?

Comment: @ThermalRaindrops62, see the link that I provided.