# Trigonometric equation $1-\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac {1}{\cos(x)}=0$

Tags: trigonometry

The equation is $$1-\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac {1}{\cos(x)}=0$$ I have tried multiplying both sides by $\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and I got $$\sin(x)\cos(x)-\cos(x)-\sin(x)=0$$ but honestly I think the only way out here is by a graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$$
$$\frac12 (\sin(2x))=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$$ $$\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$$ $$\frac12 (\sin(2x))=\frac{2}{\sqrt2}(\sin(x+\frac{π}{4}))$$ $$\sin(2x)=\frac{4}{\sqrt2}\left(\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) \right)$$ $$\sin(2x)=2\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$ $$2\sin^2\left(x+\frac{π}{4}\right)-1=2\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{π}{4}\right)$$ $$2\sin^2\left(x+\frac{π}{4}\right)-1-2\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{π}{4}\right)=0$$ $$2{\color{green}{\sin^2\left(x+\frac{π}{4}\right)}}-2\sqrt2 {\color{green}{\sin\left(x+\frac{π}{4}\right)}}-1=0$$

Comment: after this you get an easy quadratic to solve for x. this is my method, hope yall like it

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by $\sin(x)\cos(x)$:
$$
\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)\tag1
$$
Square and multiply by $4$:
$$
4\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)=4+8\sin(x)\cos(x)\tag2
$$
Apply $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$:
$$
\sin^2(2x)-4\sin(2x)-4=0\tag3
$$
Solve:
$$
\sin(2x)=2-2\sqrt2\tag4
$$
Since $2+2\sqrt2\gt1$, we don't want that solution.

$(4)$ yields the $4$ possible solutions:
$$
\scriptsize x\in\left\{\color{#AAA}{\frac12\sin^{-1}\left(2-2\sqrt2\right),\frac\pi2-\frac12\sin^{-1}\left(2-2\sqrt2\right),}\pi+\frac12\sin^{-1}\left(2-2\sqrt2\right),\frac{3\pi}2-\frac12\sin^{-1}\left(2-2\sqrt2\right)\right\}\tag5
$$
Note that $x\mapsto\pi+x$ negates $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ but leaves $\sin(x)\cos(x)$ unchanged. Thus, each solution will have a non-solution offset by $\pi$.

The first two solutions in $(5)$ give $\sin(x)\cos(x)=-\sin(x)-\cos(x)$, so we only want the last two solutions.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, I like your method.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $\sin x+\cos x=y,$

$ y^2=?,$

$-\sqrt2\le y\le\sqrt2\ \ \ \ (1)$

$$\dfrac{y^2-1}2=y\iff y^2-2y-1=0\iff(y-1)^2=2$$

$\implies y=1\pm\sqrt2$

By $(1), y\ne1+\sqrt2$

Comment: y²=sin²(x)+2sin(x)cos(x)+cos²(x) but how does that relate to my q?

Comment: @Xetrez, So, we have  $$\sin x+\cos x=1-\sqrt2$$

Comment: Then... you may draw a right triangle to find the length of 3 sides and eventually the angle $x$.

Comment: But how do i relate y to the equation i have? There's no sin(x)+cos(x)

Comment: @Xetrez, Have you noticed the line after Hint?

Comment: Sorry, i'm just not seeing this at all.I'm very confused about: where does the sqrt(2) come from and hoe you get that equation to solve for after

Comment: And i've done another step forward into $$\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$$

Comment: @Xetrez, $$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)$$  right?  Now  for real $x,$ $$-1\le\sin\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)\le1$$

Comment: Where does that sin(x+π/4) come from

Comment: @Xetrez, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213545/solving-trigonometric-equations-of-the-form-a-sin-x-b-cos-x-c

Comment: i actually solved it myself, with no relation with any of the helps provided here, but thanks still!

Comment: @Xetrez, Feel free to post your method and accept that

Comment: sure! i just did

Answer (score 2):

Apply the half-angle substitution $t= \cot \frac x2$ to $1-\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac {1}{\cos x}=0$
$$t^4+ 4t -1=0$$
which factorizes as

$$(t^2+2a t+\frac{2a^3-1}a)(t^2-2a t+\frac{2a^3+1}a)=0$$
with $a^6+\frac14a^2-\frac14=0$, which yields $a^2=\frac12$. Plug it into above equation to obtain a pair of real roots
$$t=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1}}{\sqrt2}$$
Thus, the solutions for $x$ are
$$x=2n\pi+2\cot^{-1} \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1}}{\sqrt2} $$