# Trigonometry, $\sin A + \cos A = 1/4$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

this is my first question. So, recently I came across a question "$\sin(A) + \cos(A) = 1/4$. Find $\sin(A)\cos(A)$ without a calculator." I was interested and I try to solve it. But unfortunately, I cannot solve it. I think it is about double angles formula $\sin(2A) = 2\sin A\cos A$ but I still didn't know how to solve it. Pls help me.

Comment: **Hint :** Square it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. For example, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset math formulas

Comment: If you want to find $A$ directly, this is a particular case of a general question here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213545/solving-trigonometric-equations-of-the-form-a-sin-x-b-cos-x-c

Answer (score 1):

Squaring both sides we have
\begin{align}
&\sin^2 (A) + 2 \sin (A) \cos (A) + \cos^2(A) = \dfrac{1}{16}\\
\implies &1-\cos ^2 (A) + 2\sin (A) \cos(A) + \cos ^2(A) = \dfrac{1}{16}\\
\implies & 2 \sin (A) \cos(A) = - \dfrac{15}{16}\\
\implies & \sin(A) \cos(A) = -\dfrac{15}{32}
\end{align}
where the only tool we used was that $\sin^2x = 1 - \cos^2 x$.

Comment: Not that the OP asked for this extra tid-bit, but I see there are four solutions for $A$ on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$. More solutions occur at shifts of integer multiples of $2 \pi$ of course.

Comment: Because I don't want to.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read properly the question...