# Solving the trigonometric equation $A\cos x + B\sin x = C$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a simple equation which i cannot solve for $x$:

$$A\cos x + B\sin x = C$$

Could anyone show me how to solve this. Is this a quadratic equation?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/201405/4583) for the general approach and an example.

Comment: [My picture-answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/181870/409) to a related question may be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

$A\cos x+B\sin x=C$ so if $A\neq 0, B\neq 0$ then $$\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\cos x+\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\sin x=\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$ in which $$\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\le1,~~\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\le1,~~\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\le1$$ This means you can suppose there is a $\xi$ such that $\cos(\xi)=\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}},\sin(\xi)=\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$ and so...

Comment: +1 . I think the condition needed here is merely $\,A\neq 0\;\;or\;\;B\neq 0\;$ , though if one of them is zero then the equation is much easier.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes dear Don. It is my wrong using of notation. I'll fix. Sorry for being Lazy in typing.

Comment: Are there no easier solutions?

Comment: @71GA: I don't know :) But there is a great comment above under question. Follow that.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We can also utilize Weierstrass substitution ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution), [2](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml)), which will convert the given equation to a Quadratic equation in $\tan \frac  x2$