# Help with $\int \frac{1}{(\sin x + \cos x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Kindly solve this question

$$\int \frac{1}{(\sin x + \cos x)} dx$$

I reached up to

$$\frac{(1+\tan^2x)}{1-\tan^2x + 2\tan x}$$

Comment: Use the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution).

Answer (score 8):

HINT:

$$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)$$ or $$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt2\cos\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)$$

More generally, set $a=r\cos\phi,b=r\sin\phi$ to find

$a\sin x+b\cos x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin\left(x+\arctan2(b,a)\right)$

Similarly,  set $a=r\sin\psi,b=r\cos\psi$ to find

$a\sin x+b\cos x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos\left(x-\arctan2(a,b)\right)$

arctan2 has been [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) here

Comment: Was just in the process of writing this exact formula. +1, this is by far the easiest way to go.

Comment: thanks, nice solution but can't we do it in any easy way?

I converted sinx  and Cosx into tan(x/2) form and reached as mentioned

Comment: @sunnymalhotra: This *is* the easy way! If you follow this hint you will end up integrating a secant, which is a standard formula.

Comment: Nice answer. Could you also show how they are derived for future reference?

Comment: You should add a factor of $\mathrm{sgn}(a)$ in $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin\left(x+\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)\right)$.

Comment: @Alizter, Hav ea look into http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444887/solving-the-trigonometric-equation-a-cos-x-b-sin-x-c and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Simplifying_a_sin(x)_%2B_b_cos(x)

Comment: @fvel, I would like use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation in place of sgn$(a)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Your formula is only correct to the sign, mind elaborating how $\mathrm{atan2}(x,y)$ is going to replace the $\mathrm{sgn}$-function?

Comment: @fvel, If $a<0, b\ge0,$ $\arctan 2(y,x)=\arctan\dfrac yx+\pi$ $$\implies\sin[x+\arctan2(y,x)]=\sin[\pi+x+\arctan\dfrac yx]=-\sin[x+\arctan\dfrac yx]$$ etc.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It's easier to just multiply by $\mathrm{sgn}(a)$ since that'd give you one simple formula instead of a piecewise one defined for $a>0$ and $a<0$. Although guess both work

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
  Use the formula $$
\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sin x = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}. $$ Now use the substitution $u = e^{ix}$. Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin x + \cos x} &=\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin x + \cos x}\cdot \frac{\sin x - \cos x}{\sin x - \cos x}\\
&=\int \frac{\sin x - \cos x}{\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x}\mathrm dx\\
&=\int \frac{\sin x}{1 - 2\cos^2 x}\mathrm dx-\int \frac{\cos x}{2\sin^2 x -1}\mathrm dx\\
&=\int \frac{1}{2\cos^2 x-1}\mathrm d(\cos x)-\int \frac{1}{2\sin^2 x -1}\mathrm d(\sin x)\\
\end{align}